Create an exact copy of my current excel with only values but not formulae using OfficeJS or any other 3rd party library
I am working on an excel with OfficeJS web addin. I have a fully loaded excel with data across different sheets and formulae.
I want to download an exact copy of the current workbook without formulae , After extensive research I've learnt that using OfficeJS it is not possible to create a new excel while already working on an excell workbook as the context change will crash the excel application.
So i was trying to implement my requirement with the help of 3rd party libraries like xlsx, xlsx-populate and ExcelJS.
Using ExcelJS i was able to download a copy of the current workbook but was not able to copy the cell formatting, fonts, colors etc.
Is there a better front end library or a better way to achieve my requirement of downloading an exact copy of my current workbook.
Note: I am using the taskpane to load Angular components and download the file with the help of OfficeJS.
I've pasted the code that I tried below. Please suggest if modifying my code will help me or I need to use a better library for my requiement.


async downloadWorkbook3() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async(context) => {
      const currentWorkbook = context.workbook;
      const sheets = currentWorkbook.worksheets;
      sheets.load('items/name,items/visibility');
      await context.sync();

      // Create a new ExcelJS workbook
      const newWorkbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

      for (const sheet of sheets.items) {
        if (sheet.visibility !== 'Visible') {
          continue; // Skip hidden sheets
        }
        const worksheet = sheet;
        worksheet.load(['name']);
        await context.sync();

        const usedRange = worksheet.getUsedRange();
        usedRange.load(['values']);
        await context.sync();

        // Load formats separately
        usedRange.load(['format/*']);
        await context.sync();

        // Create a new worksheet in the ExcelJS workbook
        const newSheet = newWorkbook.addWorksheet(worksheet.name);

        const values = usedRange.values;
        for (let row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
          for (let col = 0; col < values[row].length; col++) {
            const value = values[row][col];
            const newCell = newSheet.getRow(row + 1).getCell(col + 1);
            newCell.value = value;

            const cell = usedRange.getCell(row, col);
            cell.load(['format/fill', 'format/font', 'format/borders']);
            await context.sync();


            newCell.fill = this.convertFill(cell.format.fill);
            newCell.font = this.convertFont(cell.format.font);
            
          }
        }
      }

      // Write the workbook to a Blob
      const buffer = await newWorkbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
      const blob = new Blob([buffer], {
        type: 'application/octet-stream'
      });
      // Create a download link and trigger the download
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = 'Workbook_Copy.xlsx';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error downloading workbook:', error);
  }
}

convertFill(fill: Excel.RangeFill): ExcelJS.Fill {
  if (!fill || !fill.color) return {
    type: 'pattern',
    pattern: 'none'
  };
  return {
    type: 'pattern',
    pattern: 'solid',
    fgColor: {
      argb: fill.color.replace('#', '')
    }
  };
}

// Convert Office.js font to ExcelJS font
convertFont(font: Excel.RangeFont): Partial < ExcelJS.Font > {
  if (!font) return {};
  return {
    name: font.name,
    size: font.size,
    bold: font.bold,
    italic: font.italic,
    color: font.color ? {
      argb: font.color.replace('#', '')
    } : undefined
  };
}



